# view reolver mapping not working proeprly in maven webapp project

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

i made java based project without xml mapping file 
I created a Controller as below:

```
public class TestController {
//@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/test")
public String helloController()
{
    return "helloworld";
}
```

i have created jsp file named helloworld.jsp under WEB-INF/view folder
 my view resolver as follow:

```
 @Configuration
 @ComponentScan(basePackages="com.oyolife.controller")
 public class LoveCalCulaorAppConfig {
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver view()
{
 InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver=new InternalResourceViewResolver() ;
viewResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/view/");
viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
return  viewResolver;
 }
 }
```

when in run this programmer following error occur:
**WARNING: No mapping for GET /lovebalance/myweb.com/WEB-INF/view/helloworld.jsp
**
it means tomcat adding prefix and suffix from view reslover but it is not mapped helloworld.jsp properly

additionaly webinitilizer code is here

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext xwac=new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    xwac.register(com.oyolife.config.LoveCalCulaorAppConfig.class);
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherservlet=new DispatcherServlet(xwac);
    //register dispatcher servlet with spring
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic 
    mycustdispatcherservlet=servletContext.addServlet("mydispatcherservlet",dispatcherservlet);

    mycustdispatcherservlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    mycustdispatcherservlet.addMapping("/myweb.com/*");
  }
```

Comment: Did you add @Controller to your TestController or is that just missing from your post?

Comment: yes i have added that and its working find if I return String to @ResponseBody instead of returning viewResolver

Answer (score 0):

actually nothing wrong with the code ,1.right click on server>add/remove project>remove project
2. right click on project>run>maven install
3.right click on project>run>run on server
now its working fine